# R Improving code performance

Tags: r

Given a data table (A) with coordinates identifying the location of node centroids, and another data table (B) with coordinates identifying locations where samples environmental data were taken, how would I determine the location in B to which a given node in A is closest, without using a for loop? Currently, I can do the following:

**Example**

```
#Locations of nodes of interest
node_latitude = seq(33, 36.6, by=0.4)
node_longitude = seq(-53, -56.6, by=-0.4)
node_longitude_mat = matrix(NA, 10, 10)
node_coordinates = vector("list")
for(i in 1:length(node_latitude)) {
  node_longitude_mat[,i] = rep(node_longitude[i],nrow(node_longitude_mat))
  node_coordinates[[i]] = cbind(node_latitude, node_longitude_mat[,i])
}

node_locations = as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", node_coordinates), 
                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(node_locations) = c("LATITUDE", "LONGITUDE")
plot(node_locations)

#Sampling locations providing environmental data, e.g., temperature
#Locations of nodes of interest
sample_values_01 = runif(100, -10, 20)
sample_values_02 = runif(100, -10, 20)
sample_values_03 = runif(100, -10, 20)
samp_latitude = 30:39
samp_longitude = -50:-59
samp_longitude.mat = matrix(NA, 10, 10)
samp_coordinates = vector("list")
for(i in 1:length(samp_latitude)) {
  samp_longitude.mat[,i] = rep(samp_longitude[i],nrow(samp_longitude.mat))
  samp_coordinates[[i]] = cbind(samp_latitude, samp_longitude.mat[,i])
}

samp_locations = as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", samp_coordinates), 
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
samp_locations = cbind(samp_locations, sample_values_01, sample_values_02, 
                       sample_values_03)
colnames(samp_locations) = c("LATITUDE", "LONGITUDE", "TEMPERATURE_01", 
                             "TEMPERATURE_02", "TEMPERATURE_03")
plot(samp_locations$LATITUDE~samp_locations$LONGITUDE)
points(node_locations$LATITUDE~node_locations$LONGITUDE, pch = 2)

require(geosphere)
test = vector()
value_coordinates = vector("list")
for(i in 1:length(node_locations$LONGITUDE)) {
  for(j in 1:length(samp_locations$LONGITUDE)) {
    test[j] = distHaversine(p1=c(node_locations$LONGITUDE[i], 
                              node_locations$LATITUDE[i]), 
                         p2=c(samp_locations$LONGITUDE[j],
                              samp_locations$LATITUDE[j]))
  }
  value_coordinates[[i]] = c(node_locations[i,], 
                             samp_locations[which.min(test),3:5])
}

table_test = as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", value_coordinates), 
                               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(table_test) = colnames(samp_locations)
require(data.table)
table_test = data.table(table_test)
```

Which is fine for 10x10 tables. This gets cumbersome with hundreds or thousands of rows and columns are included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a solution that avoids for loops by using `outer()` on the longitudes and lattitudes individually.

```
delta_LAT <- outer(node_locations$LATITUDE, samp_locations$LATITUDE,`-`)
delta_LON <- outer(node_locations$LONGITUDE, samp_locations$LONGITUDE,`-`)
distance <- (delta_LAT^2) + (delta_LAT^2)
# index of the nearest node to each sample
apply(distance,2,which.min)
```

you can implement this as a one liner like so:

```
function(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    apply(outer(x2, x1[indx],`-`)^2 +
          outer(y2, y1[indx],`-`)^2,2,which.min))
```

This has one major complication, which is that `outer()` may try and allocate more space than you have in available memory.  You can handle this by breaking the job up into chunks in response to hitting memory limits like so:

```
f <- function(x1,y1,x2,y2,chunkSize=length(x1)){
    stopifnot(length(x1) == length(y1))
    stopifnot(length(x2) == length(y2))
    force(chunkSize)
    incomplete = TRUE

    # define an inner function here so we can use 
    # scoping assigment (`<<-`) to extend the variable 
    # `out` from within the call to `tryCatch()` 
    inner <- function(i,chunkSize){
        indx <- seq.int(chunkSize * (i-1) + 1,
                        min(chunkSize*i,length(x1)))
        out <<- c(out,
                 apply(outer(x2, x1[indx],`-`)^2 +
                       outer(y2, y1[indx],`-`)^2,2,which.min))
    }
    while(incomplete){
        out <- integer(0)
        cat('chunk size:',chunkSize,'\n')
        tryCatch( {
            for(i in seq.int(ceiling(length(x1)/chunkSize)))
                inner(i,chunkSize)
            incomplete=FALSE
        },error=function(e){
            if(!grepl("^cannot allocate vector of size",e$message))
                # re-raise any error other than memory limit errors
                browser()#;stop(e)
            print('too big')
            if(chunkSize > 1)
                chunkSize <<- floor(chunkSize/2)
            else
                stop('cannot allocate memory for even one comparison')
        })
    }
    return(out)
}
```

with 1000 by 10,000 rows per table, the job takes a little under one second.

```
x1 <- runif(1000)
y1 <- runif(1000)
x2 <- runif(10000)
y2 <- runif(10000)  
system.time({a = f(x1=x1, x2=x2, y1=y1, y2=y2)})
#> user  system elapsed 
#> 0.72    0.11    0.87
```

with 1000 by 123,456 rows per table, the job takes about 13 seconds

```
x1 <- runif(1000)
y1 <- runif(1000)
x2 <- runif(123456)
y2 <- runif(123456) 
system.time({a = f(x1=x1, x2=x2, y1=y1, y2=y2)})
#> user  system elapsed 
#> 9.41    3.10   12.61
```

and you can save about one second by pre-specifying the chunkSize

```
x1 <- runif(1000)
y1 <- runif(1000)
x2 <- runif(123456)
y2 <- runif(123456) 
system.time({a = f(x1=x1, x2=x2, y1=y1, y2=y2,chunkSize=250)})
#> user  system elapsed 
#> 8.69    2.59   11.61
```

This of course uses the euclidean metric on longitude and latitude which may be somewhat inaccurate if near your sampling points are near the poles, so you would want to use a different metric, depending on where your data are located...